# Why libxml won't allow me to create a node with base64 text content?

Tags: c, xml, base64, libxml2

I am using libxml2 to create an xml document which contains base64 encoded text in C.
However when I try to add a element which contains base64 encoded and then print the xml the element is empty. I also added printf to check whether the encoding is done and it is printed.

this is my program:

```
xmlChar* createImportPKCS12Xml(char* userId, char* pkcs12, char* password, char* passwordForPkcs12) {
    xmlNodePtr personElem;
    xmlNodePtr userIdElem;
    xmlNodePtr pkcs12Elem;
    xmlNodePtr passwordElem;
    xmlNodePtr pkcs12PasswordElem;
    xmlDocPtr doc;
    xmlNodePtr root_node;
    xmlChar *xmlbuff;
    int buffersize;

    doc = xmlNewDoc(BAD_CAST "1.0");
    root_node = xmlNewNode(NULL, BAD_CAST "root");
    xmlDocSetRootElement(doc, root_node);
    root_node = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);

    char* base = toBase64("abdsd");
    printf(base);

    personElem = xmlNewChild(root_node, NULL, BAD_CAST PERSON_ELEM, NULL);
    userIdElem = xmlNewChild(personElem, NULL, BAD_CAST USER_ID_ELEM, BAD_CAST userId);
    pkcs12Elem = xmlNewChild(root_node, NULL, BAD_CAST PKCS12_ELEM, BAD_CAST base);
    passwordElem = xmlNewChild(root_node, NULL, BAD_CAST PASSWORD_ELEM, BAD_CAST password);
    pkcs12PasswordElem = xmlNewChild(root_node, NULL, BAD_CAST PKCS12_PASSWORD_ELEM, BAD_CAST passwordForPkcs12);
    if ((personElem == NULL)
            || (userIdElem == NULL)
            || (passwordElem == NULL)
            || (pkcs12PasswordElem == NULL)
            || (pkcs12Elem == NULL)) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    xmlDocDumpFormatMemory(doc, &xmlbuff, &buffersize, 1);

    xmlFreeDoc(doc);
    xmlCleanupParser();

    return xmlbuff;
}
```

For base64 encoding I am using openssl:

```
char* toBase64(char* str) {
    BIO *bio, *b64;
    b64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
    bio = BIO_new_fp(stdout, BIO_NOCLOSE);
    BIO_push(b64, bio);
    BIO_write(b64, str, strlen(str));
    BIO_flush(b64);
    char* output = NULL;
    int sz = BIO_get_mem_data(b64, &output);
    BIO_free_all(b64);
    return output;
}
```

With normal text there is no problem. Does someone have same problem and can help? Or can someone suggest a different way to do this with libxml2?

EDIT 1:
The problem was in toBase64 function. After I changed it everything is working :

```
char* toBase64(char* str) {
    BIO *bio, *b64;
    BUF_MEM *bufferPtr;

    b64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
    bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    bio = BIO_push(b64, bio);

    BIO_set_flags(bio, BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL); //Ignore newlines - write everything in one line
    BIO_write(bio, str, strlen(str));
    BIO_flush(bio);
    BIO_get_mem_ptr(bio, &bufferPtr);
    BIO_set_close(bio, BIO_NOCLOSE);
    BIO_free_all(bio);
        char* output;

    output=(*bufferPtr).data;
        return output;
}
```

Comment: This is probably not the solution to your problem, but AFAIK the contents of a BIO buffer are not null-terminated. You should use a function like `xmlNodeAddContentLen` to add the Base64 string to an XML node.

Comment: Thanks for tip! The problem was in toBas64 function so I changed it and now it is working correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trailing part of the encoding function looks scary:

```
char* output = NULL;
int sz = BIO_get_mem_data(b64, &output);
BIO_free_all(b64);
return output;
```

Are you sure that the output pointer is valid after `BIO_free_all()`?

Comment: I changed the toBase64 function so it returns pointer to BIO b64 and i free it after creating and printing xml. However the element is still empty.

Comment: You were actually right. The output on stdout which I thought was printed in createImportPKCS12Xml was actually printed in toBase64 function. After I edited toBase64 fucntion everything is working correctly. Thanks! I also edited question